# OpenAI Hopper Clipping Observations

Tags: openai-gym

I've been working with the Hopper environment in OpenAI Gym and noticed that the observation clips the joint velocities but that the true state is allowed to exceed these constraints. Does anyone know why this decision was made? Or is this an overlooked bug? Thanks!